# Using javstvalidate and phpmailer with a database

Tags: javascript, php, database, phpmailer

Good day. I have a form on my website, after filling it out, the pkhpmailer is triggered. I am using this via javascript. Everything worked well. Now I still need to transfer information from the form to the database. The problem is that the submission is triggered on the side of the javascript, as I understand it, and the logic for transferring information to the database is written in php. The question is how to get this kind of code to work.
Below I enclose my form in html, javascript and php.

```
<form class="popup__form" action="mail.php" method="POST">

        <input type="hidden" value="pmewilberries@mail.ru" name="admin_email">

        <div class="popup-close"></div>
        <legend class="form__title">
          Запишитесь на мой<br>
          бесплатный интенсив
        </legend>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Имя" name="name" data-validate-field="name">
        <input type="email" class="form__input" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" data-validate-field="email">
        <input id="phone-input" type="phone" class="form__input" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="phone"
          data-validate-field="tel">
        <button class="form__button" type="submit">Записаться на интенсив</button>
        <div class="form__license__text">
          Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете согласие на обработку персональных данных
          и соглашаетесь с <a href="https://t.ly/DSBx" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
        </div>
      </form>
```

JS

```
const validateForms = function (selector, rules, successModal) {

  new window.JustValidate(selector, {
    rules: rules,
    submitHandler: function (form) {

      const formData = new FormData(form);

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            window.open('https://www.artemdaniluk.ru/thank-you.html');
          } else {
            thanksText.innerText = `Что-то пошло не так!`;
          }
        }
      }

      xhr.open('POST', 'mail.php', true);
      xhr.send(formData);

      form.reset();
      closePopup();
      openThanksModal();

    }
  });

}

validateForms('.popup__form', {
  email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
  },
  name: {
    required: true
  },
  tel: {
    required: true
  }
}, '.thanks-popup');
```

php

```
<?php 

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'artemdaniluk');

if(!$connect) {
  echo 'Error';
} else {
  echo 'Success';
}




require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'artemdaniluk.pme@mail.ru'; 
$mail->Password = 'lrPMMJupiVsDWLdJ8ksj'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;

$mail->setFrom('artemdaniluk.pme@mail.ru'); 
$mail->addAddress($email);

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка на участие в интенсиве Wildberries';

$body = 'large html code here';

$mail->msgHTML($body);
$mail->send();

$mail->clearAddresses();
$mail->addAddress("sparkereddd@gmail.com");
$bodyAdmin = "Пользователь: " . $name . " оставил заявку. Его почта: " . $email . ". Номер телефона: " . $phone;
$mail->msgHTML($bodyAdmin);
$mail->send();


?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [the JS example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform-ajax.phps).

Answer (score 0):

Removed the submithandler from the javascript and screwed the transition to the pages of a successful request and unsuccessful in php

Comment: Don't post comments or edits as answers - edit your question.